# How can I get arrays returned from laravel foreach instead of a json array?

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to return an array of values using laravel foreach based on input values.
This is my expected output

```
    [
[
    "number": 2567046807891,
    "message": "THis is a test",
    "sender": "Oasis Agrib"
],
[
    "number": 256782248927,
    "message": "THis is a test",
    "sender": "Oasis Agrib"
]
```

]

but am getting this instead

```
[
{
"number": 2567046807891,
"message": "THis is a test",
"sender": "Oasis Agrib"
},
{
"number": 256782248927,
"message": "THis is a test",
"sender": "Oasis Agrib"
}
]
```

This is what i have tried

```
$batch = array();
                foreach($data as $v){
                    $phone_number = $v['phonenumber'];
                    $batch[] = array('number' => $phone_number,'message' => $message, 'sender' => $sender);
                }
                return $batch;
```

How can best go about this situation

Comment: how do you render on your view file.. can you post the code here.?

Comment: am pushing the array to external an API. It only accepts that format ```'msgdata'=> array(
array(
'number'=>256704733492,
'message'=>'elias',
'senderid'=>'Good'),
array(
'number'=>256774733492,
'message'=>'marvin',
'senderid'=>'Bad')
)```

Comment: have you tried casting `$batch` to array as `return (array) $batch;`

Comment: Yes but i get the same result

Comment: it will be helpful if you could post your route,controller as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an JSON structure as PHP array, you can use the function `json_decode()` and set the second flag to `true`

```
$json_string = '[
    {
        "number": 2567046807891,
        "message": "THis is a test",
        "sender": "Oasis Agrib"
    },
    {
        "number": 256782248927,
        "message": "THis is a test",
        "sender": "Oasis Agrib"
    }
]' ;  
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

You can now use `$array` as a classic PHP associative array.

Answer (score 1):

The expected outcome with curly brackets is correct. An array (also called a list) `[]` contains elements and cannot have properties/keys:

```
[
    [], // another array/list
    {}, //object
    "", //string
]
```

So in order to work with key/value pairs, you'll have to go with an object:

```
{
    "number": 256782248927,
    "message": "THis is a test",
    "sender": "Oasis Agrib"
}
```

Combine multiple objects in a list and you'll end up with the outcome you already posted:

```
[
    {
        "number": 2567046807891,
        "message": "THis is a test",
        "sender": "Oasis Agrib"
    },
    {
        "number": 256782248927,
        "message": "THis is a test",
        "sender": "Oasis Agrib"
    }
]
```

Note that an external API will not handle your 'expected' outcome as the syntax is invalid, it should return an error or discard invalid JSON.

Comment: but the api takes this format ```'msgdata'=> array(
array(
'number'=>256704733492,
'message'=>'elias',
'senderid'=>'Good'),
array(
'number'=>256774733492,
'message'=>'marvin',
'senderid'=>'Bad')
)``` How can i go about that??

Comment: Probably if you change your `return $batch;` into `return array('msgdata' => $batch);`. You're only missing the msgdata layer.

Comment: Nothing changes. I still return the curly brackets